# When import a CSS file in React app.js file

Tags: reactjs

```
ERROR in ./src/App.css 1:3
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Comment: And do you think you _do_ have an appropriate loader to handle that file type? Did you read the linked guidance? Research the topic? Without a [mre] it's very difficult to understand what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you using Webpack?**

If you are, did you install an appropriate loader for css files? If not, that's the problem.

You have to install **css-loader** and add it to your webpack config file.

1. First, run `npm install --save-dev css-loader`
2. Then, add the loader in your webpack config file, like this:

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  [...]
  module: {
    rules: [
      [...]
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```